# Cant create fragment object in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am a student who is studying android development. I am learning about fragments currently. I understand the point of them etc. and am trying to do some messing around to see them in action. However when going off the example I have been given and trying to implement if it in my own example app I am unable to create an object I am required to and cannot find why the example works and mine will not.

I tried looking through the XML and both Java classes to find where I have made my mistake and cannot find it but I know it is there.

**Java onCreate Code**

```
package org.me.gcu.pizzaapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View mainView;
    private Button submitButton;
    EditText inputEmail;
    RadioButton stuffedCrust;
    RadioButton thinCrust;
    CheckBox mushrooms;
    CheckBox sweetcorn;
    CheckBox onions;
    CheckBox peppers;
    ToggleButton extraCheese;
    private Fragment fr1;
    private Fragment fr;


    Order order = new Order();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        stuffedCrust = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.stuffedCrust);
        thinCrust = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.thinCrispy);
        mushrooms = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxMushrooms);
        sweetcorn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxSweetcorn);
        onions = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxOnions);
        peppers = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxPeppers);
        extraCheese = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton);

        fr1 = new FragmentOne();
        fr = fr1; //pick fragment

        //Set fr as the current Fragment to show
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment,fr); //send fragment into Frame
        transaction.commit(); //update the view
    }
```

**Fragment Object Code**

```
package org.me.gcu.pizzaapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class FragmentOne extends Fragment

{

    public FragmentOne()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here's how you replace a fragment using `FragmentManager` in Java: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#java. `FragmentManager` is responsible for instantiation, not you

Comment: Can you explain what your example "does not work" means?

Comment: @dominicoder I am unsure what you have asked actually means. I have been given an example of how fragments work and asked to implement fragments into an example application I had already created beforehand. However when I am attempting to do "fr = new FragmentOne" I am met with an error stating the type expected is Fragment and type provided is FragmentOne which is a creation of an object.

In the provided example this method works and no issues appear when executing the code "fr = new FragmentOne".

Comment: @KenWolf Hi, I understand this but why is it that in my given example the instantiation is performed with the line "fr = new FragmentOne" if that is not how it is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am met with an error stating the type expected is Fragment and type provided is FragmentOne

See, that explains the actual issue you're having.

"the example works and mine will not" does not explain the issue you're having. See the difference?

On to your problem.

`FragmentOne` is apparently not a `Fragment`, which is what the code expects. How can that be when your class extends `Fragment`? Look at your imports:

Your Activity imports:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

Your `FragmentOne` class imports:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Therefore, your activity is looking for an object of type `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` but you are giving it an object of type `android.app.Fragment`.

Replace `import android.app.Fragment` (which is deprecated) with `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` in your `FragmentOne` file.